# Path for a local image in dockerfile on Windows

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to build an image based on la local image file "file.tar.gz" that I have in the same folder than the docker file. I'm not able to reference it in my image file. I'm running docker desktop on windows.

These are the results that I obtain when building the dockerfile:

FROM /file.tar.gz, FROM ./file.tar.gz or FROM .\file.tar.gz   --> I get "invalid reference format"

When I use FROM \file.tar.gz o c:\aboslute\path\file.tar.gz the builder tries to connect to a remote repository

When I use FROM c:/Aboslute/Path/file.tar.gz I get "invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase" (only "invalid reference format" if I use only lowercase in the absolute path).

Do any of you know how to reference my local image in the FROM instruction of the dockerfile?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: build docker will auto use your local image

Comment: `FROM` never references a local file, always a named Docker image that's loaded into Docker or can be pulled from a registry.  What originally produced the `file.tar.gz`?

Answer (score 1):

You have to load your local image.

You can do it running:

```
docker load < yourimage.tar.gz
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I need to add files, install libraries, etc... in that image. Once the image is loaded, how do I reference it in the dockerfile?

Comment: You need to add files to your container or to your image? Be sure you have clear the concepts of image and container...

Comment: I need those files and libraries in my image, definitively. Thank you for your comments